# How freemarker custom function compile with normal order?

Tags: freemarker

i tried to build a web app with freemarker.
when i define and used a custom function like (fetchVarFromDB is a custom function):

```
1: <#assign a=1 />
2: xxx(some crud ops which update the db values)
3: <#assign b=fetchVarFromDB() />
```

line 3 always be compile first. But i need it executed order by line 1,2,3,
because line 2 updated some db values.

how could i do that?

Comment: why not preparing data model first and then merge it into the template?

Comment: i didn't use the freemarker to build the pages(like html,jsp);
i used it to orgnize a sequence of operations to make automattic operation instead of manually. so every line may be an operation of db;

Comment: Things in a FreeMarker template are executed in the order as they are in the template source code. So there's some oversight there.

Comment: how about ajax ,to contact with back service

Comment: @ddekany  For original methods/directives of freemarker, they were executed in order as the are in the template, that's no problem. But when you create a custom function, and use it in your templates, it will be executed first of all the tags/functions.  [official example](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_method.html)

Comment: @李振纲 i used freemarker to organized a sequence of ops storage in db, then they could be loaded and run during the java run-time on server side. It maybe not suitable for ajax to do that.

Comment: @Never I don't understand what you mean by custom functions being executed before other tags/functions. Functions/methods are executed when they are called from the template. I also don't see where the linked official documentation page says otherwise. Can you show a concrete example?